# Spring Cloud Task execution fails when running via SpringCloud dataflow server 2.11.2 with Invalid TaskExecution ID, but works fine with 2.10

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, java-17, spring-cloud-task, spring-boot-3

I am writing a spring cloud task(Spring Boot 3, Java 17)  that reads a flat file and inserts it into a database. So this is a multiple databases scenario. Running via SpringCloud dataflow server 2.112, it fails with " Invalid TaskExecution, ID ". Please see the exception below.

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?
I have tried debugging it and I noticed that tablePrefix is  "TASK_" always and not "BOOT3_TASK_"

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 50 not found
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.doTaskStart(TaskLifecycleListener.java:184) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.start(TaskLifecycleListener.java:312) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource-scdf:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataflow?schema=public"
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      jdbc-url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataflow?schema=public"

  datasource-app:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_task"
    username: root
    password:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**Datasource Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomCloudTaskConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-scdf")
    public DataSourceProperties customOperationsDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-scdf.configuration")
    public DataSource customOperationsDataSource() {
        return customOperationsDataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type( HikariDataSource.class )
                .build();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager taskOperationsTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager( customOperationsDataSource() );
    }

}
```

**DefaultTaskConfigurer**

```
@Component
public class CustomTaskConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {

    public CustomTaskConfigurer(@Qualifier("customDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

}
```

I have tried setting the table Prefix through Spring profile, but no luck

**Fix**

```
@Component
public class CustomTaskConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    public CustomTaskConfigurer(@Qualifier("springCloudDataSource") DataSource dataSource, TaskProperties taskProperties, ApplicationContext context) {
        super(dataSource, taskProperties.getTablePrefix(),context);
    }

}
```

Also ensure the database configuration properties/name defined in the task matches with what SCDF server is passing upon execution

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by inserting TaskProperties to  CustomTaskConfigurer

Answer (score 0):

It is very important that your Task application is registered with bootVersion=3

The REST docs provides more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.11.2/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-registry-post

On the dashboard registration page there is a dropdown for the Boot Version.

You can find more info on [Boot 3.x support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.11.2/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-boot3)